# How can the original contributer be shown in a Tumblr theme?

Tags: themes, tumblr

I've been googling for a while, and browsed http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes but I haven't found the way to show the "original poster" under reblogs in my theme.

So NOT the source (whom I reblogged it from), but the user who originally contributed it to Tumblr (and the link to his / her post.

Hope somebody knows. Thanks! //r

Answer (score 1):

Use reblog's variables containing `Root`:

> `{ReblogRootName}` — the title of the blog this post was created by.
>
> `{ReblogRootTitle}`    — the URL for the blog this post was created by.
>
> `{ReblogRootURL}`  — the title of the blog this post was created by.